# Como faço para meu código mostrar os mais altos de cada especie?

Tags: sql

Estou tentando da seguinte forma (link do exercício: [SQL Teaching - GROUP BY](https://www.sqlteaching.com/#!group_by))

> SELECT * FROM friends_of_pickles GROUP BY species;

Tabela:

- 1    Dave    male    human   180
- 2    Mary    female  human   160
- 3    Fry     male    cat     30
- 4    Leela   female  cat     25
- 5    Odie    male    dog 40
- 6    Jumpy   male    dog 35
- 7    Sneakers    male    dog 55

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando o `ORDER BY`, crescente `ASC` ou decrescente `DESC`.

`SELECT * FROM friends_of_pickles GROUP BY species ORDER BY nome_da_coluna (ASC|DESC);`

**EDIT<sup>1</sup>:**

Referência W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

**EDIT<sup>2</sup>:**

Depois que respondi reparei que tinha um link do exercício.

O correto no exercício seria usando apenas os campos height_cm e species.

`SELECT MAX(height_cm), species FROM friends_of_pickles GROUP BY species`